# How locus of points of parallel lines in homogeneous coordinates, forms infinity?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, projective-space, homogeneous-spaces

In the diagram shown in link, what does writer mean when he says "locus of these points forms the line **r**". In the diagram "**r**" is curved, why is it called a *line*. I am facing difficulty in grabbing the concept of infinity in homogeneous coordinates, like, how does `[wa,wb,0]` define infinity. Can you please depict this visually?

[Projective geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQtF9.png)

Comment: It is a little difficult to depict things at infinity, because they are pretty far away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blue annotation is misleading. All the parallelel lines are considered to converge to a *single* point at infinity.

Consider a pencil of converging lines, and let the intersection point escape to infinity in some direction: the lines become parallel. Now rotate the figure; you can imagine that the meeting point describes a circle of infinite radius. The latter is called the line at infinity. Its exact shape is immaterial, though you can say that a circle of infinite radius has zero curvature, i.e. is straight everywhere.